# How to accomplish timeout behavior using TestScheduler?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive, scheduler, reactive-programming

I've created the following helper method to assist with testing observables:

```
    public static void ExecuteObservableTest<T>(IObservable<T> observable, Action action, Action assert, bool expectTimeout, int timeout = 500)
    {
        Exception ex = null;
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        observable.Timeout(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout)).ObserveOn(scheduler).Subscribe(_ => { }, e => ex = e);
        action();
        scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout).Ticks + 1);
        assert();
        if (expectTimeout) Assert.IsNotNull(ex);
        else Assert.IsNull(ex);
    }
```

Things work great as long as I'm not expecting a timeout.  For test cases where I do expect a timeout, this method never reaches the OnException method.  What is the proper way to achieve this using TestScheduler?

I should also note that the timeout is a soft timeout, meaning that  if the observable hasn't completed within the allotted time, it's never going to complete - but there's no corresponding timeout defined within the observable itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the `TestScheduler` to `Timeout` with [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228946(v=vs.103).aspx)

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
observable.Timeout( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeout), scheduler)
          .Subscribe(_ => { }, e => ex = e);
```

Comment: Thanks, @supertopi.  When I attempt to use both the Timeout overload and ObserveOn(scheduler) in the same statement, the latter seems to be ignored, so my tests expecting a timeout now pass while the others (formerly passing) now fail.  I've added an if-else block to toggle on expectTimeout.  Do you know why this happens, and is there a more elegant solution than an if statement?

Comment: Sure. Create an `ITestableObserver` with `scheduler.CreateObserver<T>`. Subscribe the testable observer to your observable under testing. After advancing TestScheduler for a desired amount of time, you can check if the timeout happened, by something like `testObserver.Messages.AssertEqual(OnError(timeout))`

Comment: @ket: Using `ObserveOn` with `TestScheduler` does not really make sense. `ObserveOn` has a different purpose, e.g. you can make sure that you can modify your application's UI from a subscription if you `ObserveOn` the scheduler associated with the UI (like `DispatcherScheduler`). `TestScheduler` is used to "compress" time and should be passed as an argument to operations that waits for time to pass like `Timeout`.

Comment: I dont think the above comment is good advice, or at least complete advice. It is very common for `ObserveOn` to be part of a unit tested class, and hence common for it to be used with a `TestScheduler`. However, this will usually be indirectly used as the `ObserveOn` would be in the class under test and the `TestScheduler` would be injected from the test. In prod the `IScheduler` would be something like the `DispatcherScheduler`, but under test, you would replace it with the `TestScheduler`